# Initializing multi-dimensional std::vector without knowing dimensions in advance

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector, push-back

**Context:** I have a class, E (think of it as an organism) and a struct, H (a single cell within the organism). The goal is to estimate some characterizing parameters of E. H has some properties that are stored in multi-dimensional matrices. But, the dimensions depend on the parameters of E.

E reads a set of parameters from an input file, declares some objects of type H, solves each of their problems and fills the matrices, computes a likelihood function, exports it, and moves on to next set of parameters.

**What I used to do:** I used to declare pointers to pointers to pointers in H's header, and postpone memory allocation to H's constructor. This way, E could pass parameters to constructor, and memory allocation could be done afterwards. I de-allocated memory in the destructor.

**Problem:** Yesterday, I realized this is [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814013/double-free-inside-of-a-destructor-upon-adding-to-a-vector)! So, I decided to try vectors. I have read several tutorials. At the moment, the only thing that I can think of is using push_back() as used in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663186/initializing-a-two-dimensional-stdvector). But, I have a feeling that this might not be the best practice (as mentioned by many, e.g., [here](https://www.techiedelight.com/initialize-two-dimensional-vector-cpp/), under method 3).

There are tens of questions that are tangent to this, but none answers this question directly: What is the best practice if dimensions are not known in advance?

Any suggestion helps: Do I have any other solution? Should I stick to arrays?

Comment: There are many different ways to deal with `vector` dimensions, as outlined in the [link you provided](https://www.techiedelight.com/initialize-two-dimensional-vector-cpp/). They are all perfectly fine, but suited for different use cases. So what is the actual problem you are having with them? In any case, there is nothing wrong with using pointers-to-pointers (or even just pointers) as long as you follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) properly, which most people don't at first.

Comment: *I de-allocated memory in the destructor.* -- And if any of those allocations fail in the middle somewhere when you were initially allocating, how did you handle this?  I'm asking, because the pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer stuff always has that little important detail people don't think about -- if something fails on memory allocation.

Comment: *What is the best practice if dimensions are not known in advance?* -- `resize()`, `push_back()`, `emplace_back()`, `insert()` (did I forget any?).  So out of those, which one fits what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I don't, @PaulMcKenzie. Probably one reason what I was doing is considered bad practice. (This is partly related to Remy's point too: It appears that I am not following the law of three--e.g., I am not handling allocation fails.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, all of them work. But, I am not sure which one is most efficient.

Comment: @kei2e Don't optimize prematurely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `push_back()` should be fine, as long as the vector has reserved the appropriate capacity.

If your only hesitancy to using `push_back()` is the copy overhead when a reallocation is performed, there is a straightforward way to resolve that issue. You use the `reserve()` method to inform the vector how many elements the vector will eventually have. So long as
`reserve()` is called before the vector is used, there will just be a single allocation for the needed amount. Then, `push_back()` will not incur any reallocations as the vector is being filled.

From the example in your [cited source](https://www.techiedelight.com/initialize-two-dimensional-vector-cpp/):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
matrix.reserve(M);
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    // construct a vector of ints with the given default value
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(N);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        v.push_back(default_value);
    }

    // push back above one-dimensional vector
    matrix.push_back(v);
}
```

This particular example is contrived. As @kei2e noted in a comment, the inner `v` variable could be initialized once on the outside of the loop, and then reused for each row.

However, as noted by @Jarod42 in a comment, the whole thing can actually be accomplished with the appropriate construction of `matrix`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(M, std::vector<int>(N, default_value));
```

If this initialization task was populating `matrix` with values from some external source, then the other suggestion by @Jarod42 could be used, to move the element into place to avoid a copy.

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
matrix.reserve(M);
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(N);
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        v.push_back(source_of_value());
    }

    matrix.push_back(std::move(v));
}
```

Comment: `matrix.push_back(std::move(v));` to avoid extra copy, or directly `std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix(M, std::vector<int>(N, default_value));`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense; Thanks!
Question: Isn't it more efficient to perform the inner loop (`v.push_back()`) once--i.e. two separate loops instead of nested ones?

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, answer updated.

Comment: @kei2e That's a good point, but Jarod42's suggestion is more straightforward in that case. Contrived examples for tutorials are like that.

Comment: @kei2e BTW, consider taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: That is smart; thnx @Jarod42.
If anyone is interested, [here](https://github.com/kei2e/Memory-Allocation/blob/25174f6e1793fd1e879e2f8a7a93fb6c36006cc4/allocate.cpp) is an implementation of several methods for a 3D matrix based on suggestions in this answer. If speed is of concern, pointer and vector+move methods are similar, but vector (with separate loops) is ~25% faster (I believe, at the cost of inefficient resource allocation).

Comment: If speed is a concern, creating one big flat vector, and having the method for indexing (`z * size² + y * size + x`) is better (less allocation, cache, ...)

Comment: I had a chance to test this today @Jarod42 and it turns out that's not necessarily the case. (I have updated [my example](https://github.com/kei2e/Memory-Allocation/blob/403b7371aee8d479622e455d17e97d1d74b9d969/allocate.cpp) to reflect it.) I believe, when vector is large, the operations required to concatenate (and de-concatenate) indices become costly. This method is indeed faster in allocation, but significantly slower in accessing the vector elements.

Comment: @kei2e: You don't iterate in the same way/order (order (i, j, k) != order(k, j, i)) [Demo](https://quick-bench.com/q/CcEkodjt2gJUsT3hRSKkLoxOkOk) (but indeed, with big enough array, first indirections overhead is smoothed).