# Does the implicitly defined copy constructor in C++ call copy constructor for members too right?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor, default-copy-constructor

Just want to double check that the default (implicitly defined by compiler) copy constructor for C++ classes performs the copy constructor on each member variable as well using the old value to get the copied value for each member and for atomic objects just uses a bit copy (e.g. ints and floats)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ copy constructor a class that contains other objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810163/c-copy-constructor-a-class-that-contains-other-objects)

Comment: "Default constructor" is a technical construct, which makes this question confusing, since you are in fact referring to the *implicitly defined copy constructor* and not to a *default constructor* (either user or implicitly defined. Consider rewording the question to something like: "Will implicitly defined copy constructor call the member copy constructors?" or the like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is exactly what it does.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The default copy constructor in C++ will be member-wise copy initialization for every member in the type.

As to how exactly the copy is done for primitive types such as `int` and `float` I cannot say for certain.  My guess is it's implementation specific but most compilers just do a bit by bit copy.