# Default assignment operator= in c++ is a shallow copy?

Tags: c++, operators, shallow-copy

Just a simple quick question which I couldn't find a solid answer to anywhere else.  Is the default operator= just a shallow copy of all the class' members on the right hand side?

```
Class foo {
public:
  int a, b, c;
};

foo f1, f2;
...
f1 = f2;
```

would be identical to:

```
f1.a = f2.a;
f1.b = f2.b;
f1.c = f2.c;
```

This seems to be true when I test it but I need to be sure I'm not missing some specific case.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810163/c-implicit-copy-constructor-for-a-class-that-contains-other-objects/1810320#1810320

Answer (score 61):

I'd say, default `operator=` is a *copy*. It copies each member.

The distinction between a shallow copy and a deep copy doesn't arise unless the members being copied are some kind of indirection such as a pointer. As far as the default `operator=` is concerned, it's up to the member being copied what "copy" means, it could be deep or shallow.

Specifically, though, copying a raw pointer just copies the pointer value, it doesn't do anything with the referand. So objects containing pointer members are shallow-copied by default `operator=`.

There are various efforts at writing smart pointers that perform clone operations on copying, so if you use those everywhere in place of raw pointers then the default `operator=` will perform a deep copy.

If your object has any standard containers as members, then it may be confusing to (for example) a Java programmer to say that `operator=` is a "shallow copy". In Java a `Vector` member is really just a reference, so "shallow copy" means that `Vector` members aren't cloned: source and destination refer to the same underlying vector object. In C++ a `vector` member *will* be copied, along with its contents, since the member is an actual object not a reference (and `vector::operator=` guarantees the contents are copied with it).

If your data member is a vector of pointers, then you don't have either a deep copy *or* a shallow copy. You have a semi-deep copy, where the source and destination objects have separate vectors, but the corresponding vector elements from each still point to the same, uncloned object.

Comment: What is going to be used for the copy of the elements, their copy constructor or their copy assignment?

Comment: @Gauthier: assignment.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, default `operator=` is a shallow copy.

By the way, the **actual** difference between `shallow copy` and `deep copy` becomes visible when the class has *pointers* as member fields. In the absence of pointers, there is no difference (to the best of my knowledge)!

To know  the difference between them, see these topics (on stackoverflow itself):

- [What is the difference between a deep copy and a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)
- [Deep copy vs Shallow Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657810/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy)

Comment: @Steve is right, the compiler will generate calls to the assignment operator of each member, which often results in a deep copy.

Comment: @Ben: I know that assignment operator gets called for each member. The question is : what if the class has pointers? It's not a deep-copy. Hence the default `operator=` is a shallow copy.

Comment: If they're raw pointers, yes, shallow copy.  If they're smart pointers, it could go either way, depending on how the smart pointer assignment operator was implemented.

Comment: @Ben: Yes. And that is what I said in my post.

Answer (score 13):

"shallow" versus "deep" copy is less meaningful in C++ than it is in C or Java.

To illustrate this, I've changed your `Foo` class from three `int`s to an `int`, an `int*`, and a `vector<int>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Foo {
public:
  int a;
  int *b;
  std::vector<int> c;
};

using namespace std;

int main() {
  Foo f1, f2;
  f1.a = 42;
  f1.b = new int(42);
  f1.c.push_back(42);
  f2 = f1;

  cout << "f1.b: " << f1.b << " &f1.c[0]: " << &f1.c[0] << endl;
  cout << "f2.b: " << f2.b << " &f2.c[0]: " << &f2.c[0] << endl;
}
```

When this program is run, it yields the following output:

```
f1.b: 0x100100080 &f1.c[0]: 0x100100090
f2.b: 0x100100080 &f2.c[0]: 0x1001000a0
```

The `int` is boring, so I've left it out.  But look at the difference between the `int*` and the `vector<int>`: the `int*` is the same in f1 and f2; it's what you would call a "shallow copy".  The `vector<int>` however is different between f1 and f2; it's what you would call a "deep copy".

**What's actually happened here** is that the default `operator =` in C++ behaves as if the `operator =` for all of its members were called in order.  The `operator =` for `int`s, `int*`s, and other primitive types is just a byte-wise shallow copy.  The `operator =` for `vector<T>` performs a deep copy.

So I would say the answer to the question is, No, the default assignment operator in C++ does not perform a shallow copy.  But it also doesn't perform a deep copy.  The default assignment operator in C++ recursively applies the assignment operators of the class's members.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it just copies the object member-wise, which can cause issues for raw pointers.

Answer (score 5):

I personally like the explanation in [Accelerated c++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020170353X). The text (page 201) says:

If the class author does not specify the assignment operator, the compiler synthesizes a default version. The default version is defined to operate recursively - assigning each data element according to the appropriate rules for the type of that element. Each **member of a class type** is assigned by calling that member's assignment operator. **Members that are of built-in type** are assigned by assigning their values.

As the members in the question are integers, I understand that they are deep copied. The following adaptation of your example illustrates this:

```
#include<iostream>
class foo {
public:
  int a, b, c;
};

int main() {
    foo f1, f2;
    f1 = f2;
    std::cout << "f1.a and f2.a are: " << f1.a << " and " << f2.a << std::endl;
    f2.a = 0;
    std::cout << "now, f1.a and f2.a are: " << f1.a << " and " << f2.a << std::endl;
}
```

which prints:

```
f1.a and f2.a are: 21861 and 21861
now, f1.a and f2.a are: 21861 and 0
```

Answer (score 2):

No.  `operator=` doesn't perform a copy at all.  It's an *assignment* operator, not *copy* operator.

The default assignment operator assigns each member.

Comment: assignment operator does a deep copy of everything if you define it, if you don't it will do a shallow copy of pointers

Answer (score 1):

If a, b and c were classes then the assignment operator for those classes would be called, so the compiler isn't simply copying the raw memory contents - but as others pointed out, any raw pointers will be copied without any attempt to duplicate the pointed-to thing, thus giving you the potential for dangling pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by the code snippet below, the = (assignment) operator for STL performs a deep copy.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    /* performs deep copy */
    map <int, stack<int> > m;
    stack <int> s1;
    stack <int> s2;

    s1.push(10);
    cout<<&s1<<" "<<&(s1.top())<<" "<<s1.top()<<endl;   //0x7fff5fbfe478 0x100801200 10

    m.insert(make_pair(0, s1));
    cout<<&m[0]<<" "<<&(m[0].top())<<" "<<m[0].top()<<endl; //0x100104248 0x100803200 10

    m[0].top() = 1;
    cout<<&m[0]<<" "<<&(m[0].top())<<" "<<m[0].top()<<endl; //0x100104248 0x100803200 1

    s2 = m[0];
    cout<<&s2<<" "<<&(s2.top())<<" "<<s2.top()<<endl;   //0x7fff5fbfe448 0x100804200 1

    s2.top() = 5;
    cout<<&s2<<" "<<&(s2.top())<<" "<<s2.top()<<endl;   //0x7fff5fbfe448 0x100804200 5
    cout<<&m[0]<<" "<<&(m[0].top())<<" "<<m[0].top()<<endl; //0x100104248 0x100803200 1

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    map <int, stack<int*> > mp;
    stack <int*> s1p;
    stack <int*> s2p;

    s1p.push(new int);
    cout<<&s1p<<" "<<&(s1p.top())<<" "<<s1p.top()<<endl;    //0x7fff5fbfe360 0x100805200 0x100104290

    mp.insert(make_pair(0, s1p));
    cout<<&mp[0]<<" "<<&(mp[0].top())<<" "<<mp[0].top()<<endl;  //0x1001042e8 0x100806200 0x100104290

    mp[0].top() = new int;
    cout<<&mp[0]<<" "<<&(mp[0].top())<<" "<<mp[0].top()<<endl;  //0x1001042e8 0x100806200 0x100104320

    s2p = mp[0];
    cout<<&s2p<<" "<<&(s2p.top())<<" "<<s2p.top()<<endl;    //0x7fff5fbfe330 0x100807200 0x100104320

    s2p.top() = new int;
    cout<<&s2p<<" "<<&(s2p.top())<<" "<<s2p.top()<<endl;    //0x7fff5fbfe330 0x100807200 0x100104340
    cout<<&mp[0]<<" "<<&(mp[0].top())<<" "<<mp[0].top()<<endl;  //0x1001042e8 0x100806200 0x100104320

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    vector<int> v1,v2;
    vector<int*> v1p, v2p;

    v1.push_back(1);
    cout<<&v1<<" "<<&v1[0]<<" "<<v1[0]<<endl;   //0x7fff5fbfe290 0x100104350 1

    v2 = v1;
    cout<<&v2<<" "<<&v2[0]<<" "<<v2[0]<<endl;   //0x7fff5fbfe278 0x100104360 1

    v2[0] = 10;
    cout<<&v2<<" "<<&v2[0]<<" "<<v2[0]<<endl;   //0x7fff5fbfe278 0x100104360 10
    cout<<&v1<<" "<<&v1[0]<<" "<<v1[0]<<endl;   //0x7fff5fbfe290 0x100104350 1

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    v1p.push_back(new int);
    cout<<&v1p<<" "<<&v1p[0]<<" "<<v1p[0]<<endl;    //0x7fff5fbfe260 0x100104380 0x100104370

    v2p = v1p;
    cout<<&v2p<<" "<<&v2p[0]<<" "<<v2p[0]<<endl;    //0x7fff5fbfe248 0x100104390 0x100104370

    v2p[0] = new int;
    cout<<&v2p<<" "<<&v2p[0]<<" "<<v2p[0]<<endl;    //0x7fff5fbfe248 0x100104390 0x1001043a0
    cout<<&v1p<<" "<<&v1p[0]<<" "<<v1p[0]<<endl;    //0x7fff5fbfe260 0x100104380 0x100104370

    return 0;
}
```