# C++ Why does the debugger trigger a breakpoint in the destructor of this small block of code?

Tags: c++

Hello this block of code is not compiling for some reason and for the life of my I can't figure it out. It gives me an error when it calls the destructor could someone tell me why please

The error is:

> Exception thrown test.exe has triggered a breakpoint"

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class X {
public:
    X(int i)
    {
        p = new (int);
        *p = i;
    }
    ~X() { delete p; }
    int* p;
};

int main()
{
    X x1(1);
    X x2(2);
    x2 = x1;
}
```

Comment: Please add the text of the error message.

Comment: You should provide a copy constructor and an overload for the assignment operator, otherwise the allocated pointer would be deleted twice, leading to that error. That's a runtime error and no compiler error BTW.

Comment: Related: [Default assignment operator= in C++ is a shallow copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5096464/2402272)

Comment: The fact that you were able to get that error in the first place indicates that your code was able to compile. Please change the title.

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign

x2 = x1;

the pointer will be copied from x1 to x2 and it attempts to delete the same object twice.

Comment: Ohhh thanks you so much!

Comment: Worth mentioning that, and how the default copy constructor and assignment operator are generated by the compiler.