# c++ is it possible to copy default constructor with pointers or references?

Tags: c++

I have an object Person:

```
class Person
{
...
public:
Person(string firstName, string lastName);
...
}
```

And in my main I have a copy constructor to it, should it work?
Or I need to make sure that members fields are not shared between the two objects?

```
Person p1("Arthur", "Janes");
Person p2(p1);
```

Comment: How do you want to "copy a constructor" (sic!)?

Comment: Where are the pointers/references? Please include an SSCCE.

Comment: I want the default copy constructor, does the String property is a pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your class only contains correctly copyable members, then that's fine. Specifically, if they're stored as `std::string` then you're good; if you're storing pointers or references, then there may be danger.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your class members are copiable, and you don't have any other specific copy constructor in the class, you should be able to use a copy constructor. A default copy constructor is generated when you define a class:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1810320/1270003