# Vector element type can not have both destructor and non copyable member

Tags: c++

I have a vector of which the element class has non copyable member. Now I want to add a destructor to this class. But the compiler complains: "call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'TestClass'". Here is a sample code:

```
    struct TestClass
    {
       TestClass(int a){}
       ~TestClass() = default; // Will pass the compile if this line is removed
       std::unique_ptr<int> data_;
    };

    int main() {
      std::vector<TestClass> test;
      test.emplace_back(100);
      return 0;
    }
```

What's the difference of the class with or without the destructor, please?

Comment: Also possible duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3734247/1896169 https://stackoverflow.com/q/19606492/1896169

Comment: In short, the presence of a destructor inhibits the move constructor. When you add the destructor, the compiler no longer generates a move constructor, which means that `std::vector` has to try to copy instead of move, but `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied

Comment: Thank you for your help! Add the default move constructor and it works:

        TestClass(TestClass&&) = default;

Comment: Make sure you make it a noexcept move constructor: `TestClass(TestClass&&) noexcept = default;`. There are cases where `std::vector` still has to copy the object if you don't mark it `noexcept`